# How to convert an HTML table to JSON and use the JSON with JSON.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json.net, jsonserializer

I'm asking this question because I think it's one that we run into from time to time.  I needed to take an HTML table that had been manipulated client side and send the resulting table data to the server for processing.  Additionally, I wanted to map this using JSON.NET directly to my business object(s).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a jQuery plugin for handling this.  Please check out:

http://www.fletchzone.com/post/jQuery-Convert-HTML-Table-to-JSON.aspx

Best,

Fletch